# How do I comment big part of a code that i do not want to compile.

Tags: comments

I m tired to comment line by line the things I desired to comment, is there a a way of selecting part of the code, and get it inmediatly in comment?

Comment: many editors will let you comment/uncomment a region as a single command but if not you can (usually) put `\iffalse` at the start and `\fi` at the end of a section to be skipped

Comment: `\usepackage{comment}` and `\begin{comment}... stuff...\end{comment}`. Or use your editor to do the job.